# Transistor as a switch, what does the inductor do?

Tags: transistors, load, inductive

[image]

I dont understand what the inductor in this circuit is actually doing. Is there a current flowing through the coil when my input is 0 ? If so, it should be DC so the coil isnt really doing anything special while the transistor BE diode is blocking, so if I increase the base current (with a rectangle voltage source at input) , the current through the inductor changes, inducing a very high voltage since Ul=L*di/dt which flows through the diode as a safety precaution.

What is this ciruit used for ?

Comment: There won't be any "very high voltage" if `D1` does its job.  There will be a big pulse of current through D1 when the transistor switches off, but the diode will prevent the voltage on the collector from going more than one diode drop above V+.

Comment: If you remove the diode, then when the transistor switches off, the voltage on the collector will go however high it takes to force some current through the "off" transistor, possibly destroying it.

Comment: Karl S. - Hi, Now 5 years later, I don't know where you found the schematic in the question. However the same schematic is on this page: [Reviseomatic - Bipolar Transistor Used as a Switch](https://reviseomatic.org/help/e-MOSFET-BJT/Semiconductor%20Switches.php) where its operation is explained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inductor isn't something you want to have in the circuit.

But if your load is a motor or a relay coil, for example, it will behave like an inductor, and you'll have to design your control circuit to not destroy itself when switching that load.

Answer (score 2):

The "inductor" is simply simulating an inductive load, such as a relay. It doesn't matter what is actually there in real life. You probably won't be placing an inductor between the collector of the transistor and your V+. It's just a placeholder for whatever load you are switching with the transistor.